# Confused about a regex

Tags: regex, reluctant-quantifiers

I want to match expressions that begin with `"${"` and end with `"}"` in the expression `${foo} and ${bar}`.

The regex `.*\$\{.+\}.*` matches the entire expression, of course.

My understanding was that changing to the reluctant quantifier would solve the problem, but I find that `.*\$\{.+?\}.*` also matches the entire expression.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as the suggestion by 1800 INFORMATION i would change the dot to something else:

```
\$\{[^\}]+\}
```

As the `+` will match as much as it can even a `}` if you have two occurances of `${}` in the string.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by removing the `.*` at the start and the end of the expression - it is probably this that is matching everything. If you try this does it work?

```
\$\{.+\}
```

Comment: rememebr that potenetially .* matches the empty string, and you can find an empty string anywhere :) (this entirely depends no the regex engine in use)

Answer (score 0):

The "+" quantifier is greedy, so it matches as much as it can, while +?, matches just enough.

For example, for "${foo} something ${bar}"

".+"  --> match = "${foo} something ${bar}"
".+?" --> match = "${foo}" and "${bar}". You will have to iterate to get all the matches.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: That's what I understood before.  My confusion was why ".+?" wasn't matching as little as possible.